# How to join merge/join two arrays in ballerina

Tags: arrays, ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake

Lets say I have two int arrays.

1. How can I merge these two arrays?
2. How can I create a new array out of these two arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To merge one array to another array, use array [push function](https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/lang.array/0.0.0#push).
2. To merge two arrays and create a new array, use [spread operator](https://ballerina.io/learn/distinctive-language-features/advanced-general-purpose-language-features/#spread-operator-x).

Sample code can be found in the below snippet.

```
import ballerina/io;

public function main() {
    int[] x = [1, 2];
    int[] y = [3, 4, 5];
    int[] z = [6, 7, 8];

    // Answer to Q1.
    // Pushes all of the members in `y` to x
    x.push(...y);
    // `x` changes now.
    io:println(x); // [1,2,3,4,5]
    // `y` remains the same.
    io:println(y); // [3,4,5]

    // Answer to Q2.
    // Creates a new list with the members from `x` and `y`.
    int[] arr = [...x, ...z];
    io:println(arr); // [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

    io:println(x); // [1,2,3,4,5]
    io:println(y); // [3,4,5]
    io:println(z); // [6, 7, 8]
}
```